# Calculate no of times a record has been viewed

Tags: administration

How can I calculate number of times a record has been viewed?

Comment: if that is viewed by VF page only - add some action to VF page that is executed when page is loaded and increase some counter.

Comment: Actually, what do you put in 'view'? Is it when your record appear in search results or just open in separate detail page? Or maybe, retrieved via SOAP/REST API?

Comment: Sid.. you may want to look into this post  [**Page Views Counter widget in salesforce**](http://www.codespokes.com/2013/06/page-views-counter-widget-in-salesforce.html)  and  [**Working with Cookies on Sites pages**](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2010/05/working-with-cookies-in-summer-10.html)

Comment: also in reports, and list views. what is considered "view"

Answer (score 1):

If you display the record in a Visualforce page, you can include Google Analytics code in the page. This will generate stats on sessions, page-views and users. [Here's](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_site_googleAnalyticsTracking.htm) some sample code.

Comment: yes but google analytics is a bit excessive.

why not just a an initized counter in that visualforce page writing back to the record.

Google analytics opens up a much larger security conversation, and assumes the user has/wants GA.

What we do know is they have salesforce.